# Replace custom gallery shortcode with default gallery shortcode

Tags: shortcode, gallery, customization

I want to replace my custom gallery shortcode in my post content with the default Wordpress shortcode (in pre get posts). I will be doing this in only a certain instance where it will need to be formatted in the default gallery shortcode format (in order to work with exporting to Apple News).

How can I search through the content for my custom gallery shortcode:

```
[showgallery id="1234"]
```

And then replace it with the default one:

```
[gallery ids="1234,1235,1236,1237,1238"]
```

I can handle the changing it from one id to the several ids by just creating a custom function that will just grab the one id, fetch that post, grab the array of images within that post (I use ACF galleries), and then return the list of ids.

So I just need to know how to search through the content, find each showGallery shortcode, and then for each of those shortcodes grab the id, send it to my custom function, remove the old shortcode, and then replace it with the new one that would be returned by my function.

I found this which seems close, but still can't figure out fully how to remove the old one, etc.

[Extract attribute values from every shortcode in post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172275/extract-attribute-values-from-every-shortcode-in-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make a regex filter as a `the_content` filter,

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_regex_filter', 1); // Execute as early as possible

function my_regex_filter($content) {
    $regex = get_shortcode_regex(array('showgallery'));
    $content = preg_replace('/'.$regex.'/s', '[$1gallery$3$4$5$6]', $content );
    return $content;
}
```

or rewrite your `add_shortcode` function.

```
remove_shortcode('showgallery');
add_shortcode('showgallery', 'my_showgallery');

function my_showgallery($args) {
    return gallery_shortcode($args);
}
```

I would recommend the second, because it is cleaner and faster.

**Edit**:

### Rewriting the shortcode for external plugins.

In your `functions.php` define the ***plugin version*** of your shortcode:

```
remove_shortcode('showgallery');
add_shortcode('showgallery', 'my_showgallery');

function my_showgallery($args) {
    return gallery_shortcode($args);
}

function my_template_gallery($args) {
    // Here put your custom gallery code…
}
```

Add to your `header.php` the following two lines:

```
remove_shortcode('showgallery');
add_shortcode('showgallery', 'my_template_gallery');
```

Now you got the rendered WP shortcode everywhere except on your templates.

Comment: I was thinking of something like your first answer, but the actual TODO: part is what I would need input/help with figuring out.

Comment: updated @KKranzo ;) **edit** i'm not sure about the regex flags...

Comment: And I can't really rewrite the add_shortcode because this would need to run only when the content was being pulled by a certain plugin (the export to Apple News plugin).

Comment: this is also possible... remove the old shortcode > add the new > filter content > remove the new > add the old

Comment: It looks like your updated first answer is close, but I would need to locate each shortcode, run a function using the id attribute from the shortcode, then replace the shortcode with the return/output of the function. So it seems like there needs to be a step in between the $regex line and $content line in your example, correct?

Comment: @KKranzo like i said i am not sure about the [regex modifiers/flags](http://php.net/manual/de/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), try `'/'.$regex.'/ims'`

Comment: @KKranzo tried it myself (i was curious)... so i added brackets to the replace `[$1gallery$3$4$5$6]` and the `s` flag is fine. should work now

Comment: It looks like the recommendation to rewrite the shortcode for external plugins would work! The only thing is that I also will need to set the template gallery in my rss feed templates, but I should be able to just add the same code that you said to add to header.php to the top of those feed template files and be all set, right?

Comment: yes, that is correct. you can even add another shortcode funtion for your rss feed if you want. no limits here. :)